# Run firefox extensions in xulrunner

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, xulrunner

I am just wondering if is it possible to run extension like colorzilla / firebug in xulrunner.

In fact I am creating my own extension now and I was trying addon_sdk but this is very problematic to put extension icon/button next to location bar.
So I decided to work with xul, and I know that problem doesn't exist here. And Of course the best way to learn is analyze other code, a changing it. But I can't run any extension in xulrunner. Any hint / help ?

Comment: I think this question even more important now than in 2013 as XUL support has been abandoned from the official Firefox and someusers can require you run some XUL apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`xulrunner`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XULRunner) is just a runtime or platform. **You'd need an actual app on top of that**. In that regard, Firefox, Thunderbird, Seamonkey, InstantBird, etc. can be considered (complex) `xulrunner` apps.

Existing extensions may run, with or without modifications in such a `xulrunner` app. Well, likely with modifications, as most extensions use APIs specific to Firefox or Thunderbird or ...

The add-on SDK is not generally isn't a good fit for generic `xulrunner` apps: It is too much tailered against Firefox specifically.